# Pass dictionary to function without altering previously processed values

Tags: python, dictionary, copy, deep-copy

I am trying to alter specific entries in a list of dictionaries using a function. However I cannot alter one entry without altering them all. I have tried every combination of dict() and .copy() I can think of and I can't get this to work. How can I fix this?

```
a = dict(population[10][2])
b = a.copy()
print(a == b)
print(route_length(a))
print(route_length(b))
```

True

(3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0)

(3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0)

```
c = dict(mutate(a))
print(route_length(c))
```

(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0)

```
d = dict(mutate(b))
print(route_length(c))
print(route_length(d))
```

(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 7, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0)

(3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 7, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0)

```
c == d
```

True

I'm not expecting any specific answers from 'mutate', just that 'c' and 'd' be differnt. 'mutate' randomly rearranges some lists in, my print out is giving the lengths of the differnt lists. I've just been using to show that something is happening and that something different is happening each time.

Comment: can you clarify what is the input/outpout expected

Comment: Can you provide an [mre]? Including the data (minimal example).

Comment: What is `mutate` doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.copy()` creates a *shallow copy* - a new dictionary object will be created and reference to the objects in existing dictionary will be inserted into the new one.

What you need is *deep copy* which creates a new dictionary with copy of all the objects recursively:

```
import copy
a = dict(population[10][2])
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Now any modification in `b` will not be reflected in the original copy of `a`.

Comment: Worth noting that the reason deep copy is needed here is that `a` seemingly contains mutable objects and the function `mutate` mutates those objects (not just the list). Neither of these details were in the original question so could be worth clarifying in the answer for future readers.